# Is this Modular arithmetic property true?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $a \equiv b \mod (nm)$, then is it always true that $$a \equiv b \mod n$$ $$a \equiv b \mod m$$

I feel like it's kind of obvious because if $a-b = k_1nm$, then $a-b = k_2n$, ($k_2 = k_1n$) but I can't find any resources on the topic, so maybe I'm wrong

Comment: You're not only correct but have just provided a proof!  You have that $nm|(a-b)$, so $n|(a-b)$, and therefore the modular equivalencies hold.

Comment: Yes, **congruences *persist* mod factors of the modulus**, and your proof is correct (it essentially employs *transitivity* of "divides", i.e. $\, n\mid nm\mid a\!-\!b\,\Rightarrow\, n\mid a\!-\!b),\,$ where $\,x\mid y\,$ means $\,x\,$ divides $\,y.\,$ See the linked dupe for more.

Comment: See also [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1311447/242)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $m,n\geq 2$ are relatively prime, then the mapping
$${\Bbb Z}_{mn}\rightarrow{\Bbb Z}_m\times {\Bbb Z}_n:a\mapsto (a\mod m, a\mod n)$$
is a ring isomorphism. In this way, $a\equiv b\mod mn$ is equivalent to $a\equiv b\mod m$ and $a\equiv b\mod n$.

Comment: That's the only thing I've found (that this property holds when m and n are coprimes), but why would not work when m and n are not coprimes?

Comment: @ALEJANDRO CRT is a red herring. The inference you seek uses only transitivity of divisibility so it holds for all $\,n,m.\ \ $